# Get all files not present int a datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, file, datatable, getfiles

I have a MySQL table with a list of file name.
I would like to get a list of all file in a directory only if their names are not present in the table.

I can put the list of the database's file in a Datatable and write something like:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
 foreach (Datarow row in dataTable.Rows)
   for (int i=0; i<files.Length; i++)
      if (row[0].equals(files[i]) {
          files[i].delete();
          break;
       }
```

The upper code is only a pseudo-example. Can't I directly use **Directory.GetFiles(directory)** by specifying a filter in order to don't write all the iteraction?

Comment: No, there's no way to use it, but you can reduce your code using *if(files.IndexOf(row[0].ToString()) < 0)...*

Comment: for example if you wanted to get a list of files that end with `.txt` you could do the following 
`var files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Where(name => name.EndsWith(".txt")).ToList();` so if  you could do that.. why couldn't you replace the `.EndsWith` method with `.Contains` and get all files that contain a particular string value..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please find code snippet below

decided to do it in steps - to have more maintainable code

```
void Main()
{
    // given a list of files from db
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("x");  
    dataTable.Columns.Add("file", typeof(string));  
    dataTable.Rows.Add("HaxLogs.txt");dataTable.Rows.Add("swapfile.sys");dataTable.Rows.Add("four.txt");
    var directory = "c:\\";
    var directoryFilesWithPaths = Directory.GetFiles(directory)
            .Select( x=> new FileEntry { Path = x, FileName = Path.GetFileName(x)});

            var directoryFiles = directoryFilesWithPaths.Select(x => x.FileName).ToList();
            var filesList = (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
                            select dr[0].ToString()).ToList();

            var filesToProcess = directoryFiles.Except(filesList);
        foreach (var file in filesToProcess)
        {
            // process file here

            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
```

}

Comment: Hi, there is a problem that I didn't say: in the datatable there are the filenames without the paths, but with **String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(tDirectory.Text, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);** I get also the paths.

Comment: I tried with **var filesToProcess = files.Select(Path.GetFileName).Except(filesList);** but doesn't works.

Comment: there is a **patch** :-)

Comment: Thank you, but in this way aren't you loosing the path + file name that I need in your last foreach? Can't we do the Select in the **var filesToProcess** of your first example, as my second comment?

Comment: look for my solution please :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104588/discussion-between-profesor79-and-helloimyourmind).

Answer (score 1):

A linq solution is:

```
Directory.GetFiles(directory)
         .Where(x => !dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => row[0].ToString()) 
                .Contains(x))
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the result is a list of all the files in the directory, not filtered.

Comment: One possible explanation is that the table contains entirely different data than the results of Directory.GetFiles. For example the table might have file names but GetFiles returns full paths.

Comment: Yes, it's as you said. I need to select all the file whose ends with the row of the database.

Comment: If by "whose ends with" you mean the file name and extension then you would just have to change this part `.Contains(Path.GetFileName(x)))`

Comment: Thank you, it works, but the professor79 solution is faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
 ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
 files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        foreach (DataRow row in tableFiles.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                if (files[i].ToString().EndsWith(row[0].ToString()))
                {
                    files.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
        }
```

I also tried with **Path.GetFileName(files[i].ToString()** in order to use the **Equals** instead of **EndsWith**, but with 8500 files, this solution takes 2 seconds, with **GetFileName** 10 seconds.

Comment: looks nice - but looping can be expensive

Comment: But in this way I still have the full file name, do you think can we improve this solution?

Comment: that's true - this info about number of files should be in you question.